# Issues with deleting records and data reading using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to programming and I'm at the very end of my first vb.net programming assignment but I can't figure this last part out.

The program is a small address book with database back-end, my problem occurs when I delete a contacts record. 
The data record being read is based off the contacts primary key, when I delete a contact record the next contact record moves up but every record below it doesn't read correctly.

I have a feeling this occurs because my code only reads the primary keys in sequential order, but I'm not sure how to go about changing it to make it work correctly.

Here's the code that relates to it reading the data when i select the record in a listview.

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim command As MySqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id= '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.Index + 1 & "'"

    Try
        connection.Open()
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            txtFirstName.Text = reader.GetString("first_name")
            txtSurname.Text = reader.GetString("surname")
            txtHouseNo.Text = reader.GetString("house_number")
            txtStreet.Text = reader.GetString("street")
            txtSuburb.Text = reader.GetString("suburb")
            cboState.Text = reader.GetString("state")
            txtPhone.Text = reader.GetString("phone")
            txtMobile.Text = reader.GetString("mobile")
            txtWork.Text = reader.GetString("work")
            txtEmail.Text = reader.GetString("email")
            txtNotes.Text = reader.GetString("notes")
            txtid.Text = reader.GetString("id")
        End While

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Close()
        command.Dispose()
    End Try
    Call txtEnable()
End Sub
```

And here's how I load the contacts to the listview

```
Private Sub loadcontacts()
    Dim command As MySqlCommand = Nothing
    Dim listquery As String = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY id"
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = Nothing

    Try
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.Open()
        End If

        command = New MySqlCommand(listquery, connection)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        command.CommandText = listquery

        With ListView1
            .Columns.Add("Name", 220, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

        End With

        ListView with the data
        While reader.Read
            Dim ls As New ListViewItem(reader.Item("first_name").ToString() & " " & reader.Item("surname").ToString)
            ListView1.Items.Add(ls)
        End While

    Catch ex As MySqlException
    Finally
        connection.Close()
        command.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems that you are assuming that the index of the focused item matches exactly the primary key of your table. This is no more true if you delete an item because there are fewer items in the listview. You shoud store somewhere in the ListView subitems the ID ( I suppose that this is the primary key), retrieve it and use it instead of the index when you want to select an item. The fix could be easy if you add the code that fills the listview

Comment: I just added in my original post the code for how I load the contacts to the listview, is this what you meant by the subitems? adding primary key ID somewhere in that? I need a little more info on how I could retrieve my primary key instead of the index

Comment: Sorry but it is a broad subject. I can offer [a link to the MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem(v=vs.110).aspx) about ListView.Subitems. You could see that the example builds 4 columns and add subitems for each column. In your query that builds the ListVIew there is the ID field and this data could be stored in one of the subitems. To read it back it is just a matter to read the corresponding subitem of the focused item

Comment: if you build a dataset/datatable and use a DGV things are much simpler - just bind the data container to the control - it populates the control for you

Comment: I just want to make sure that we're on the same page. So this is what I think I have to do: If the sub-item id =  the listview selected item, then it will execute the reader to populate the textboxes. Just not sure how I can write this in code. The sub-item part is whats getting to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that has a similar problem I figured it out.
Steve helped me get on the right track here so thank you.
I added the ID (primary key) subitem like this:

```
While reader.Read
            Dim ls As New ListViewItem(reader.Item("first_name").ToString() & " " & reader.Item("surname").ToString)
            ls.SubItems.Add(reader.Item("id").ToString)
            ListView1.Items.Add(ls)
```

then in the listview focused item I made the query like this:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text & "'"
```

Now save, update, and delete work with primary key ID reading in the correct order. Thanks for the help and I hope this helps out someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

After you delete a record, clear and reload your list.